# my setInterval time does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in javascript and angular.  This should be a simple issue but I don't know what is wrong with my code.   I don't know if i have the proper syntax for the time handler.  The code just display the time only once.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello-world',
  templateUrl: './hello-world.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello-world.component.css']
})
export class HelloWorldComponent implements OnInit {

  dateMessage: string;

  constructor() {

  setInterval(this.time_handler, 1000); 

  //Method 1: This works    
  //  setInterval(()=>  {
  //     let currentDate = new Date();
  //     this.dateMessage = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
  //  }, 1000);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

// Method 2:  This does not work  
  public time_handler() {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    this.dateMessage = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to clear your interval when your component is destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `bind` this to the function inside the interval.

```
 constructor() {

  setInterval(this.time_handler.bind(this), 1000); 

  //Method 1: This works    
  //  setInterval(()=>  {
  //     let currentDate = new Date();
  //     this.dateMessage = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
  //  }, 1000);

  }
```

Else `this` in the handle method won't point to the class.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  I knew this would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The code that does not work because `this` inside a `setInterval` will be pointing to `window` & in `window` object there is no `time_handler` function

```js
setInterval(console.log(this), 3000)
```

That is why your code does not work

But your commented code work because there you are using arrow function, & in arrow function this refers to surrounding scope.

When you use `bind` that returns a new function and it is explicitly bound